# How to define a model that has detail?

Tags: typescript, model, clean-architecture

I'm trying to make my first node app using clean architecture. So far I have a model called User and another called Invitation. I'm having a noobie doubt about how to define my Invitation model if at some point in db there is gonna be a table to store invitation detail (id, invitation_id, user_id)

Should my Invitation model look like this? or I need another model called InvitationDetail?

```
export interface Invitation {
 id: string
 name: string
 date: string
 users: User[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Invitation` model looks just fine. If there is going to be an introduction of a new table and the properties are different, you should create a new model for it (e.g. `InvitationDetails`).

If hypothetically speaking both of those tables will share similar properties and you want to increase reusability of the `Invitation` interface, you can extract the properties that are similar into a new interface and have the models [extend](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) from it. E.g:

```
interface InvitationT {
 name: string
 date: string
 users: User[]
}

export interface Invitation extends InvitationT {
 id: string
}

export interface InvitationDetails extends InvitationT {
 id: string
 invitation_id: string
 user_id: string
}
```

This answer is based on the information provided, hope it helps you :)

Comment: I undestand but what I was trying to say is that how to model a master-detail entities (like in my db, inivitation table and invitation_detail table) I have to define another model for this detail or is it ok  just using a list of users in invitation model?